# Сохранение строк с помощью SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Есть текстовое поле которое при первом запуске пусто и пользователь вбивает в него имя. При повторном запуске в поле  имя уже должно отражаться. Использую SharedPreferences для сохранения.
код :

```
public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity
{
Button saveBTB;
public  static  final  String APP_PREFERENCES  = "mySettings";
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_NAME = "Name";
SharedPreferences App_Settings;
EditText etN;

EditText etF;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

    if (App_Settings.contains(APP_PREFERENCES_NAME))
    {
        etN = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
        etN.setText(App_Settings.getString(APP_PREFERENCES_NAME,""));
    }

    saveBTB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBTB);
    saveBTB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            etN = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
            String NameProfil = etN.getText().toString();
            App_Settings = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor = App_Settings.edit();
            editor.putString(APP_PREFERENCES_NAME, NameProfil);
            editor.apply();
        }
    });

} }
```

Проект вылетает на `if`. Без этого условия все вроде работает. В чем ошибка в этом коде ? Тестирую через BlueStack.

Comment: @pavlofff поставил вместо `App_Settings` ->`APP_PREFERENCES` вылетать перестало. но при повторной загрузке текствью все равно пустой, даже если заполнен. не заполняется даже nullable string defValue

Comment: @pavlofff все делал по мануалу - http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/sharedpreferences.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объект `App_Setting` инициализуертся у вас в методе `onClick()`. Когда вы обращаетесь к нему в методе `onCreate()`, он не инициализирован - объект пустой и сравнивать там нечего и не с чем. Данному вопросу посвящены разделы документации и литературы о областях видимости переменных и о полях класса.

```
public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

    public  static  final  String APP_PREFERENCES  = "mySettings";
    public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_NAME = "Name";
    private final SharedPreferences appSettings;
    private final EditText etN;
    private final EditText etF;
    private final Button saveBTB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        appSettings = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        etN = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
        saveBTB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBTB);

        if (appSettings.contains(APP_PREFERENCES_NAME)) {            
            etN.setText(appSettings.getString(APP_PREFERENCES_NAME,""));
            }

        saveBTB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String NameProfil = etN.getText().toString();
                Editor editor = appSettings.edit();
                editor.putString(APP_PREFERENCES_NAME, NameProfil);
                editor.apply();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Исправлено несколько логических ошибок. В частности, не нужно получать ссылку на виджет каждый раз при обращении, это довольно дорогая операция, которая ничего нового при опросе после каждого клика не сообщит. Ссылки на виджеты получают один раз, в начале метода `onCreate()` и в дальнейшем используют сохраненную в поле класса ссылку.
Так же неплохо ознакомится с конвенцией оформления кода в Java, в частности имена экземпляров классов пишутся в lowerCamalCase-стиле, без всяких прочерков, это может показаться незначительным, но читать подобную самодеятельность больно для глаз и если показываете код кому то, то уж придерживайтесь конвенции. Сами имена переменным, полям класса, методам и собственно классам принято давать осмысленные, отражающие суть скрывающегося за ним, все эти `etN` вас самого начнут сильно утомлять, когда проект примет сколько-нибудь существенный объем.